# Setting up Two way SSL Authentication on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, cloud-foundry, mutual-authentication

I have a task to set up two way ssl authentication between Zuul Proxy app (client) and  one of  microservices (server). Both are Spring Boot apps.
I was able to do it locally with self signed certificates and next configs:

For server I set up SSL in yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8081
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:MyServer.jks
    key-store-password: password
    trust-store: classpath:MyServer.jks
    trust-store-password: password
    client-auth: need
```

And for Zuul Proxy app I have configured `CloseableHttpClient` with key store  and trust store configured with needed certificates:

```
@Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient zuulHttpClient() throws Throwable {
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(keyStore.getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        LOGGER.info("Loaded keyStore: " + keyStore.getURI().toString());
        try {
            keyStore.getInputStream().close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warning("IOException during loading keyStore");
        }
        final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());


        final KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ts.load(trustStore.getInputStream(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        LOGGER.info("Loaded trustStore: " + trustStore.getURI().toString());
        try {
            trustStore.getInputStream().close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warning("IOException during loading trustStore");
        }
        final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(ts);

        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(ts, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).loadKeyMaterial(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
        final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
        return httpClientBuilder.build();
    }
```

It works locally, but i have issue setting up it on PCF. I am able to push  client app, but not server app. It just freezes for a while, and fails to start on PCF, logs are okay though, no exception are thrown. Turning off SSL for server `enabled: false`, lets me push application,  so it looks like this is the issue.

So my question is, is there any trivial way to set  up 2 way ssl on PCF out of box?  I have found some topics on this, that says about configuring Gorouter, currently reading docs on this topic, but was thinking if there is more easy and clear solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently when you run apps on Cloud Foundry, they *never* listen for HTTPS requests.  They always listen for HTTP requests on the assigned port.  HTTPS is handled upstream either by the GoRouter or by your company's load balancer.  The HTTPS information is propagated to your app via the `x-forwarded-*` headers.  This means you will don't need to use `server.ssl.enabled` with your Spring Boot apps and you don't need to worry about providing any certs.

If you want to handle mTLS that get's a little trickier.  You can let the upstream LB or GoRouter handle this for you.  In a way similar to `x-forwarded-*`, it validate the client certificate and make sure it's trusted.  If it's not trusted, then the connection will fail.  If it's trusted, it will pass you the certificate information via an HTTP header, `X-Forwarded-Client-Cert`.  At this point, you know the cert is valid & trusted, and you can go further to use the cert information to make choice about authorization and access.

More about this all here:  https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-1/adminguide/securing-traffic.html#gorouter_mutual_auth

The platform also manages and assigns certificates for every application instances.  You can use these certificates to identify your clients.  More about these here:  https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-1/devguide/deploy-apps/instance-identity.html

If your operator has set all this up for you, it makes doing mTLS a bit easier. If you're doing app-to-app communication, you don't really have to do anything with certs, the platform provides & validates them for you.  If you have clients off platform that are connecting, it's trickier cause you have to give them certs and your operator has to configure the platform to trust them.  It can still be done, though and your app doesn't have to change to support that.

---

Switching gears.  If you really want to go with the traditional approach, you can do that.  I know I hinted above that wouldn't be possible.  The above information applies to HTTP routes and it's not possible for HTTP routes.  If you use a TCP route for your application though, it can work.  With a TCP route, your app just gets TCP packets so it can do whatever it wants with them.  This includes doing HTTPS.  If that's what you want, it's up to the application to handle TLS.  The platform just routes the TCP packets to your app and the app does the rest.

That means you need to provide the server certs, client certs and configure your app/server to validate them.  It's very similar to your setup locally or on a traditional server setup.  With this approach, the platform does very little for you.

There's a section here which describes creating a TCP route.  It's pretty easy and the same as an HTTP route, but just an additional flag to set the port.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#create-route

You can also read more about the differences between HTTP & TCP routes here:  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#http-vs-tcp-routes

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for such detailed response. Currently I have switched to another tasks, but once be back, will respond with more details if I be able  to succeed.